# Lectura de Tablas PDF en Java

Tags: java, pdf, tablas, itext

Hola tengo el problema de que cuando leo un archivo pdf que tiene una tabla en el y le pido que me de el valor de la fila 1 columna 1 de esa tabla pasa lo siguiente
si la tabla tiene solo un dato me lo regresa bien
pero si tiene mas de un dato toma la segunda palabra como otra columna
ejemplo:
C1
Contiene: Hola - Retorna: Hola
C2
Contiene: esto es un ejemplo - Retorna: esto

Entiendo que el problema esta en que se separa por espacios o tabulaciones pero quisiera saber si hay algun otro metodo para que pueda leer los datos de una tabla y los pueda separar por celdas

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


public class Pruebas extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    
 
   
  private DefaultTableModel tableModel;
    private String textoTabla = "";

   public Pruebas() {
    initComponents();
        tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        jButton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                abrirArchivoPDF();
            }
        });
    }

 private void abrirArchivoPDF() {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

        // Establece la ruta inicial del JFileChooser
        File directorioInicial = new File("C:\\Users\\luisa\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\MedicamentosSoto");
        fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(directorioInicial);

        fileChooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Archivos PDF (*.pdf)", "pdf"));

        int resultado = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (resultado == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File archivoPDF = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            try {
                PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(archivoPDF.getAbsolutePath());

                // Limpiar el modelo de la jTable1
                while (tableModel.getRowCount() > 0) {
                    tableModel.removeRow(0);
                }

                // Extraer el texto de la primera página del PDF
                String textoPrimeraPagina = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(pdfReader, 1);

                // Buscar la tabla que tenga "Consumo General" como encabezado
                buscarTablaConsumoGeneral(textoPrimeraPagina);

                // Procesar y mostrar la tabla en jTable1
                procesarYMostrarTabla();

                // Cierra el PdfReader
                pdfReader.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error al leer el archivo PDF", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }
private void buscarTablaConsumoGeneral(String texto) {
        // Definir una expresión regular para buscar la tabla con el encabezado "Consumo General"
        String patron = "Consumo General(.*?)(?=(Consumo General|$))";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patron, Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(texto);

        if (matcher.find()) {
            textoTabla = matcher.group(0);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No se encontró una tabla con el encabezado 'Consumo General'", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
private void procesarYMostrarTabla() {
        // Procesa el contenido de textoTabla y lo divide en filas
        String[] lineas = textoTabla.split("\n");

        // Verifica si hay al menos 19 líneas (para incluir la fila 19 como encabezados)
        if (lineas.length >= 19) {
            // Obtén los encabezados desde la fila 19 (restamos 1 porque los índices comienzan en 0)
            String[] encabezados = lineas[18].split("\\s+"); // Divide por espacios en blanco

            // Borra cualquier encabezado de columna anterior en la jTable1
            tableModel.setColumnCount(0);

            // Agrega los encabezados de columna a la jTable1
            for (String encabezado : encabezados) {
                tableModel.addColumn(encabezado);
            }

            // Recorre las filas de datos a partir de la fila 20
            for (int i = 19; i < lineas.length; i++) {
             String[] datos = lineas[i].split("\\s+", 6);


                // Verifica si la fila tiene la misma cantidad de datos que los encabezados
                if (datos.length == encabezados.length) {
                    // Agrega los datos a la jTable1
                    tableModel.addRow(datos);

                    // Muestra en la consola en qué encabezado se encuentra cada dato
                    for (int j = 0; j < datos.length; j++) {
                        System.out.println("Dato: " + datos[j] + " | Encabezado: " + encabezados[j]);
                    }
                } else {
                    // Si la fila no tiene la misma cantidad de datos que los encabezados, muestra un mensaje de advertencia
                    System.out.println("Advertencia: La fila " + (i + 1) + " no tiene la misma cantidad de datos que los encabezados.");
                }
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No hay suficientes filas para procesar la tabla", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
private void procesarTabla() {
    // Procesa el contenido de textoTabla y lo divide en filas
    String[] lineas = textoTabla.split("\n");

    // Verifica si hay al menos una línea para determinar los encabezados de columna
    if (lineas.length > 0) {
        String primeraLinea = lineas[0].trim();

        // Busca el encabezado que indica el inicio de los datos de la tabla
        int indiceInicioDatos = -1;
        for (int i = 1; i < lineas.length; i++) {
            String linea = lineas[i].trim();
            if (linea.startsWith("Consumo General")) {
                indiceInicioDatos = i + 1; // La siguiente línea después del encabezado
                break;
            }
        }

        // Si se encontró el encabezado, verifica si existe una fila 1 válida
        if (indiceInicioDatos >= 0 && indiceInicioDatos < lineas.length) {
            // Divide la fila 1 en columnas (ajusta el separador según el formato real)
            String[] datosFila1 = lineas[indiceInicioDatos].split("\\s+"); // Ajusta el separador según el formato real

            // Asegúrate de que haya al menos una columna en la fila 1
            if (datosFila1.length > 0) {
                // Busca el texto "Bata de Cirujano" en la fila 1
                for (int j = 0; j < datosFila1.length; j++) {
                    String valor = datosFila1[j];
                    if (valor.equals("Bata") && j + 1 < datosFila1.length && datosFila1[j + 1].equals("de") && j + 2 < datosFila1.length && datosFila1[j + 2].equals("Cirujano")) {
                        // Se encontró el texto "Bata de Cirujano" en la columna j
                        System.out.println("Texto encontrado en la columna " + (j + 1) + ", fila 1");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("No se encontraron datos en la fila 1.");
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No se encontró un encabezado para la tabla o datos en la fila 1.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}

private static String obtenerContenidoCelda(String[] lineas, int filaObjetivo) {
    // Verificar que las coordenadas sean válidas
    if (filaObjetivo >= 0 && filaObjetivo < lineas.length) {
        // Obtener la fila objetivo
        String fila = lineas[filaObjetivo].trim();

        // Devolver el contenido de la fila completa
        return fila;
    } else {
        return "Coordenadas de celda no válidas";
    }
}



    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton2.setText("Leer PFD");

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(65, 65, 65)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(143, 143, 143)
                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 200, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(45, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(36, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 108, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(364, 364, 364))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
           public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Pruebas().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: ¿Te fijaste si podés el _split_ con saltos de línea?

Comment: Si se puede, pero no me da el resultado deseado